# Enable pins with RAMPS and M542T stepper drivers

Tags: marlin, ramps

So, I've been building a very sturdy 3d printer (also in the future hopefully a cnc router), strongly based on this: [Arduino Controlled CNC / 3D Printer Hybrid](https://www.instructables.com/Arduino-Controlled-CNC-3D-Printer/)

I'm using a RAMPS (1.4, will upgrade to 1.6 in a few days), M542T drivers and NEMA 23 motors, I got everything to work pretty well already, but so far, I haven't connected the motor enable pins from the RAMPS to the drivers. But, I don't actually get what they are good for, I think I know what they do, when a signal is sent to them (sort of lock or unlock the movement of the motor), but the printer looks to be working fine. Still, I wanted to connect them just to have everything made properly.

I found a problem, when I tried to connect enable pins, I'm not using stepper drivers which plug into the RAMPS, so I have to run cables between them. When the X/Y/Z_ENABLE_ON in marlin are on 0 (active low) are set, everything works, well as it should I guess (or inverted I'm not sure if the M542Ts need high for enabling the motors or low), I connected the pins and when I try to move any axis, it doesn't, when I disconnect the cable the given axis moves, so I was thinking that they need high signal to work. Went to marlin, se enable_on to 1 (active high), went back, had everything connected, everything moved. But, I tried to disconnect the individual wires to see if it works as it should (when disconnected the motors shouldn't turn when given a signal I thought). The X axis moved when enable was connected or disconnected, Z also, Y one motor was moving regardless of enable connection, 1 behaved even weirder, moved in only one direction. I have pul+, dir+ and enable+ connected to 5V, pul-, dir-, enable- to the RAMPS as in this:

https://3dtoday.ru/upload/main/b03/%...%B0%D1%802.jpg

Tho I have also seen it the other way somewhere, like this:

http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-qvM7BrO1wE...mps_TB6560.png

(the M542Ts have 5V in parenthesis next to the pul+, dir+ and ena+ inputs, so I thing the way I have it right now I have it correctly, but I don't even know what could be wrong to be honest)
How would I get these to work correctly?

Can you better explain to me what they actually do? Also, could you perhaps help me a bit with the connections and Marlin settings to get them to work for the bigger drivers?

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE!

Comment: Please check the links. You have supplied truncated (`...`) links which clearly will not work. I have (hopefully) fixed the first one and pointed it to the correct Instructables page. If people can't see your images then that will reduce your chance of getting a good answer.